# Not implemented by the S3FileSystem FileSystem implementation Hadoop Jar

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, solr, hadoop2

I have added these build config in my maven pom, as i want Apache Solr Dependencies to be bundled with the Jar. other wise I was getting SolarServerException: ClassNotFound, now i am not getting that exception but a new one shown below (After Pom snippet)

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass></mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And this creates two Jar Files one with Dependencies and one simple jar.
Jar with Deps, throws this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the S3FileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:518)
    at com.myproj.core.NewWordCount.main(NewWordCount.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Please help me what did wrong, that now hadoop directly looks for s3FileSystem Implementation.

Running it with this command.

hadoop jar com.myproj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.myproj.core.NewWordCount tempdata/file01 output10/

P.S. Works totally fine with simple Jar(Without dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove the hadoop-core dependency because you also have hadoop-hdfs (even if not directly).

Comment: Was this ever resolved? If yes, please do share the resolution